# MPMediaPlayer indexOfNowPlayingItem giving current index of 9223372036854775807

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mpmediaplayercontroller

I am trying to make a music player, this is where I've put the `NSLog` to show the current index:

```
- (void) handle_NowPlayingItemChanged: (id) notification
{
    MPMediaItem *currentItem = [musicPlayer nowPlayingItem];
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [musicPlayer indexOfNowPlayingItem];
    UIImage *artworkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NoSongImage.png"];
    MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];

if (artwork) {
    artworkImage = [artwork imageWithSize: CGSizeMake (200, 200)];
}

[self.artwork setImage:artworkImage];

NSString *titleString = [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
if (titleString) {
    self.songName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",titleString];
} else {
    self.songName.text = @"Unknown title";
}

    NSLog(@"%li", currentIndex);
}
```

this is my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` for my `UITableView`:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if (songsList == YES){
    NSUInteger selectedIndex = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];
    MPMediaItem *selectedItem = [[songs objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] representativeItem];
    [musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:[MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems:[songsQuery items]]];
    [musicPlayer setNowPlayingItem:selectedItem];
    [musicPlayer play];
    songsList = NO;
}
else if (albumsList == YES && albumsSongsList == NO){
    albumsSongsList = YES;
    NSUInteger selectedIndex = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];
    MPMediaItem *selectedItem = [[albums objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] representativeItem];
    albumTitle = [selectedItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
    MPMediaItemArtwork *albumArtwork = [selectedItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
    albumSelected = [albumArtwork imageWithSize: CGSizeMake (44, 44)];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
}
else if (albumsSongsList == YES){
    albumsSongsList = NO;
    MPMediaQuery *albumQuery = [MPMediaQuery albumsQuery];
    MPMediaPropertyPredicate *albumPredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue: albumTitle forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
    [albumQuery addFilterPredicate:albumPredicate];
    NSArray *albumTracks = [albumQuery items];
    NSUInteger selectedIndex = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];
    MPMediaItem *selectedItem = [[albumTracks objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] representativeItem];
    [musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:[MPMediaItemCollection collectionWithItems:[albumQuery items]]];
    [musicPlayer setNowPlayingItem:selectedItem];
    [musicPlayer play];
    }
}
```

The BOOLS determine to the `tableView willDisplayCell` which table to load.
The above all display the `UITableView` correctly with the correct content.
The problem is, when I open Albums, and select a song, it seems to play the first song of the album (at the top of the `tableView`) instead. If I then again go back to albums and select a different song, the correct song is selected.
Then again, if I go back once more and select a song, the first song is played again and repeats so on...

In my NSLog, the reason its playing the first song due to a `currentIndex` of `9223372036854775807`

Why is it returning `NSNotFound`? The `selectedIndex` (e.g `4`) is in the array of `albumTracks`.
This happens 1/3 times for the songs also.
Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of NSNotFound on a 64 bit system? What is 2^63 - 1?

Comment: This isn't really worded as a useful answer but as a comment.

Comment: Why is it returning `NSNotFound`? The `selectedIndex `(e.g `4`) is in the array of `albumTracks`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pause or stop your musicplayer before setting nowPlayingItem. Sometimes the Shuffle mode can change the index too, try to turn it off.